# IntelliJ Live Templates: Current project name

Tags: intellij-idea

I was wondering, if there is a function to obtain the current project name in an IntelliJ Live Template. I've checked the built-in expressions, but there's no one for the current project name.

Maybe the built-in expression `groovyScript("groovy code")` will do the trick, but I don't know how.

Has anyone got this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try groovyScript("_editor.project.name") (from https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-129384#focus=streamItem-27-793397.0-0)